# Как разместить ленту новостей Яндекс / mail.ru на своем сайте

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Раньше были виджеты. Вставляешь код и на твоем сайте новости от Яндекса. Как это можно реализовать сейчас? Сайт на joomla 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому пригодится. Нашел решение. Чтобы опубликовать на своём сайте новости из ленты mail.ru нужно найти в коде главной страницы news.mail.ru или рубрики news.mail.ru/нужная рубрика найти ссылку на rss ленту и вывести новости из этой ленты при помощи RSS -> HTML конвертера.